# How to make the last span element inside a paragraph no-wrap?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a paragraph surrounded by decorative quotes. The layout is fluid, and for some width, only the decorative quote is wrapping, which I want to avoid.

**Screenshot :**

[image: *Screenshot*]

**Code : http://jsfiddle.net/84EDh/1/** (Note: not tested outside of Chrome)

```
<p>
    <span class="bigchar ldquo"></span>
    Begin paragraph [...paragraph content...] end paragraph.
    <span class="bigchar rdquo"></span>
</p>
```

css:

```
p { position: relative; }
.bigchar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
}
.bigchar:after {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
.ldquo:after {
    content: '“';
    top: -10px;
}
.rdquo:after {
    content: '”';
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

**Possible solution:**

Wrap the last word with the closing span in another span

```
[...paragraph content...] end 
<span class="nowrap">
    paragraph.
    <span class="bigchar rdquo"></span>
</span>
```

**Question:**

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the no-wrapping of the last `span` of the paragraph ?

This is not very semantic, nor easy to achieve because, as you would expect, the content of the paragraph is dynamic, hence not easy to split at the template level.

Edit: css added

Comment: Can you please post your CSS as well?

Comment: Have you tried `last-child`? `p span:last-child { white-space:nowrap; }`

Comment: I tried applying nowrap to the span's, with no luck : http://jsfiddle.net/84EDh/2/

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a `q` element?

Comment: Good question, I should indeed use a `q` but I would still have to overwrite browser specific `:before` and `:after` CSS for my needs, which drives us to Kisiou answer below

Comment: Kisiou's answer still has flaws, most importantly the one that you were trying to get rid of. I think mine is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about nesting `span` inside other `span`?

What we achieve this way is rdquo acting just as a regular text (that means: if you put either no space or non-breaking space between rdquo and last word, it's not going to break into two lines).

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/HFE9T/1/

Comment: Seem to work, how come? Simply adding a wrapping `span` on my fiddle doesn't ! What's the difference ? I see you simplified the CSS as well

Comment: the key concept is the outer span having `position: relative` and the inner having `position: absolute`. Therefore you can easily position the inner one inside outer one using `top` and `left`, while the outer one goes just with the flow of text.

Comment: Accepting your answer despite some glitches : double `span` elements, text indent and padding (fixed in my fiddle, see below) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `span`, it's better to use a `q`, because that's what `q` elements were designed for!

So the HTML becomes

```html
<p><q class="bigchar">This text is surrounded by quotes. I want
the text to wrap according it's parent width. This is no problem,
it's the default behaviour. However, I would like to avoid the
last span, containing a decoration quote, to wrap.</q></p>
```

with the CSS

```css
q.bigchar::before {content:'\201C'; font-size:2em; line-height:0;
position:relative; top:.3em; margin-right:.13em;}

q.bigchar::after {content:'\201D'; font-size:2em; line-height:0;
position:relative; top:.3em; margin-left:.13em;}
```

resulting in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/eShuS/5/).

No extra markup is needed.

Note that since I leave the `p` alone, you can put all kinds of styles (like `text-indent`) on it, and it will behave as it should.

Comment: This is a more convenient approach, but is there a way to avoid paragraph line-height impact, when using a larger font ? Like in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eShuS/6/ . Also, is there a technical interest of using `q`, appart from the semantic purpose? Is it something more than a `p` with pseudo classes attached ?

Comment: Hrm. I have tried, but I can't solve the line height problem. Not without turning the `::before` and `::after` into inline-blocks, but then you have the wrapping problem again (i.e. the end quote can appear on a line by itself). The only alternative seems to be to increase the `line-height` of the `q`. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, a `q` is an inline element, while a `p` is a block, so there are several differences in how they behave. Other than that, no, purely semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using additional span elements,  try using :before and :after on paragraph like this:

```
p:after {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '”';
    bottom: -30px;
}
p:before {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    content: '“';
    top: -10px;
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/84EDh/3/)

Comment: wow, this is brilliant! but please note that it won't handle `text-indent` well, so the only way to indent the text is by putting empty `span` on the very beginning, just like you did.

Comment: This is pretty nice, but still an issue at quote-only-wrap, here is the screenshot from your fiddle (Chrome) : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4d97a/i3xa Any suggestion to fix?

Comment: My best try : http://jsfiddle.net/84EDh/4/ ... text-indent fixed with floating the `:before` element, however, the `block` or `inline-block` nature of the `:after` element makes it impossible to stick to last word, without additional markup

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final markup and CSS to achieve the expected behaviour, inspired by Michal Rybak but without the compromises (except the two `span` in the markup) :

HTML :

```
<p>
    <span class="quote" attr-char="&ldquo;">&nbsp;</span>
    Paragraph content Here. 
    Note the no-line-break here.<span class="quote" attr-char="&rdquo;">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

The `attr-char` attribute is pretty handy to be able to change the quote characters for different languages as with the `q` element (somewhat)

CSS :

```
p .quote { 
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 30px; /* Indent text at paragraph beginning */
}
p .quote:before {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
    content: attr(attr-char); /* Take the character from markup */
}
p .quote:last-child:before {
    margin-left: 10px; /* Give the closing quote some space */
}
```

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/HFE9T/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a non-breaking spaces `\00a0` before and after the quotes:

```
<style>
  element:before {content: "“\00a0";}
  element:after {content: "\00a0”";}
</style>
```

And then work your way around with negatives margins if you don’t want those space to show.